# OneDrive App on iOS - Launch to a specific folder, from PowerApps

Tags: ios, onedrive, powerapps

My query today relates to iOS devices - and the PowerApps and OneDrive Apps.

We're developing a little PowerApps App, so we have access to some of our data on mobile devices.

Our job files are in a OneDrive shared folder.
Each Job has a known subfolder, ie:
 \Jobs\J100\, \Jobs\J101\, \Jobs\J102\, etc

I'd love to be able to click a button in the PowerApp, that launches to the correct job folder in the OneDrive App.

I can launch to the root shared folder ok. That's working fine. The link contains data that looks like this: 
/EqzFfbCPh1EqnyExz9_Z8BAmSG_BtsmvQ2crbqMO-6w?e=fZ4jaM

But I'm having trouble composing a link to a subfolder, so the OneDrive app launches straight to the correct subfolder.

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "https://[YourInstance].sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/[SiteName]/SharedDocuments/Jobs/J100/"

This link is available when you choose "People with existing access" on the popup. You can remove the code at the end (the code looks like "?csf=1&e=An7ecD").

This is working on IOs and the OneDrive app launches straight to the subfolder (test made with IOs 12.1)

Hope it will help you.